# .NET Implementing InProc & Sql State Server Hybrid Session Provider

Tags: asp.net, session

In my .NET application i kinda need a session provider which is persistent like Sql Server Session Provider but also provides good performance like InProc Session Provider. 
So the idea that i come up with is , to keep session data in memory cache of the application but also use a background thread to store/update it at sql server database. In case, IIS application recycles or somehow the data in memory cache  is lost, we will fetch session data from database into memory cache again.

I need to implement a custom session provider which works the way i explained above.However i dont know, if it is good idea or a bad one. I have searched online but there are not many custom session providers.

Any suggestions?

Comment: "use a background thread to store/update it at sql server database" - so its acceptable in this scenario for you to lose recent updates to the session state, if the background thread hadn't managed to persist it before the crash/recycle?

Comment: Yes It is acceptable. Isnt that scenario also possible if we use sql server session provider?

Answer (score 0):

As a future reference, i think what you were asking is basically use the Session State with Sql Server In-Memory. Have a look to the following guide: [ASP.NET Session State Provider for SQL Server In-Memory OLTP](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dataplatforminsider/2014/07/10/new-asp-net-session-state-provider-for-sql-server-in-memory-oltp/).

Cheers

Comment: Please provide at a synopsis of the link's content.